# Android open keyboard in Voice Input mode for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I am trying to open the keyboard in voice input mode for an editText. Some links on stackoverflow mentioned android:inputType="voice" as a solution but I cannot find "voice" as one of the parameter values available for inputType. Am I missing some dependency? How do I get the "voice" parameter to work?

Comment: i dont understand well, try to be more clear, Do you want speak and write this in the editext?

Comment: Yes. I want to open the keyboard in voice input mode when this edittext gets focus or clicked and then the user should be able to speak and that text would show up in the edittext.